# font-face in firefox 8 on linux and firefox 3.6 on winxp

Tags: font-face, firefox3.6, firefox-8

this is my CSS code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'WebMitra';
    font-style: normal !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    src: url('./fonts/bmitra.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'WebMitraBold';
    font-style: normal !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    src: url('./fonts/bmitra-b.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

and this is my result in two version of Firefox in two operating system. i want know the bug is for Firefox or operating system.

**Firefox 8 on Ubuntu 11.04**

**See problem Persian font separate with each letter.**

[image: Firefox 8 on Ubuntu 11.04]

**Firefox 3.6 on Windowx XP**

**Correct version**

[image: Firefox 3.6 on Windowx XP]

[This is live version you can test it.](http://oncetest.web-ir.ir/default-html5-generate.php)

Comment: The general consensus in the #firefox channel at irc.freenode.net is the Linux font rendering.  It will *never* be Microsoft's rendering, so...

Answer (score 0):

> The general consensus in the #firefox channel at irc.freenode.net is the Linux font rendering. It will never be Microsoft's rendering, so...